# SQL Server CLR Int64 to SQLInt64 Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, sql-server, wmi, sqldatatypes, sqlclr

I am trying to write a CLR that allows me to run a WMI Query on a SQL Server.

```
using System;
using System.Data.Sql;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Management;

public class WMIQuery
{
    [SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName = "FillRow")]
    public static IEnumerable InitMethod()
    {      
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope();    
        scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\localhost\root\CIMV2");
        scope.Connect();    
        SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("SELECT Name, Capacity, Freespace FROM Win32_Volume WHERE DriveType=3");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

        ManagementObjectCollection retObjectCollection = searcher.Get ( );    
        return retObjectCollection;
    }

    public static void FillRow(Object obj, out SqlString Name, out SqlInt64 Capacity, out SqlInt64 Freespace)
    {
        ManagementObject m = (ManagementObject)obj;           

        Name = new SqlString((string)m["name"]);
        Capacity = new SqlInt64((Int64)m["Capacity"]);
        Freespace = new SqlInt64((Int64)m["Freespace"]);
    }  
 }
```

When running that table valued function i get the following error:

> An error occurred while getting new row from user defined Table Valued
>   Function :  System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
>   System.InvalidCastException:     at WMIQuery.FillRow(Object obj,
>   SqlString& Name, SqlInt64& Capacity, SqlInt64& Freespace) .

I already found out that the problem is the the conversion:

```
Capacity = new SqlInt64((Int64)m["Capacity"]);
Freespace = new SqlInt64((Int64)m["Freespace"]);
```

I hope that someone has an idea how to solve the above problem?

My code to test this CLR is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[WMIQuery]()
RETURNS  TABLE (
    [Name] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [Capacity] [bigint] NULL,
    [Freespace] [bigint] NULL
) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [MyFirstAssembly].[WMIQuery].[InitMethod]
GO


select * from WMIQuery()
```

Comment: Is one of your row values `NULL`? You may want to switch to using `Nullable<Int64>` just in case. And if one of the values is `NULL` converting to `SqlInt64` will fail as it expects a valid `Int64`. If you could provide some sample data from your database table it would be helpful.

Comment: Please post the schema of your database table and provide some sample data.

Comment: Instead of using SQLCLR use the sys.dm_os_volume_stats view

Comment: I've added the code to test the CLR @RyanWilson.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i'm using the win32_volume class as an expample for future wmi queries that i have in mind. thanks for pointing me to the dmv anyways.

Comment: @Niklas if you want to query WMI don't go through SQL Server. Calling SQLCLR like this is a lot more expensive that using the DMVs. The DMVs work on Linux where WMI isn't available too.

Comment: @Niklas Have you tried testing for `DBNULL.Value` on your columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use and check whether that row and column has proper values which can be converted to the Int64 or not. Try how to check this [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int64.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Please do the following before casting

```
bool success = Int64.TryParse(Convert.ToString(m["Capacity"]), out long number);
if (success)
{
   Capacity = new SqlInt64((Int64)m["Capacity"]);
}
else
{
   Capacity = 0;
}
```

Comment: Because it is needed string as parameter. It need parameter in the format as - 'public static bool TryParse (string s, out long result);' Here s is string.

Comment: Or you could use `Nullable<Int64>`

Comment: That might be or conditional operator or something also like string.IsNullOrEmpty....

Comment: If the column holds `Int64` values it should either be a valid `Int64` or `DBNull`.

Comment: Yes, But we do not know datatype here. As the name here Capacity it might be other thing some text values or something else.

Comment: If the OP would add to their post we may have a clearer picture, but as they are trying to cast those columns to `Int64` I would expect that that is the data type of the column.

Comment: Yes it might be otherwise it will give error but in that case also the value should be either 0 or greater than 0 not NULL. As NUL to Int64 will also give the error.

Comment: I know, but the database can hold NULL values if the column is nullable. So using `Nullable<Int64>` would take care of the conversion problem, then they would just check for `null` and give it a default `Int64` value to pass to `SqlInt64`

Answer (score 2):

The type of Disk m["Capacity"] is UInt64.
I've used this function to find out what data type was used.

```
m["Capacity"].GetType().ToString();
```

I've modifided the CLR to output just the datatype for that purpose.

After knowing the type i've done some research how to convert a UInt64 to Int64 and finally found the soultion:

```
Int64 int64cap;
Int64.TryParse(m["Capacity"].ToString(), out int64cap);
```

I don't know if this is the proper solution, but it works for me.

Here's the complete code

```
public class WMIQuery
{
    [SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName = "FillRow")]
    public static IEnumerable InitMethod()
    {


        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope();

        scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\localhost\root\CIMV2");
        scope.Connect();

        SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("SELECT Name, Capacity, Freespace FROM Win32_Volume WHERE DriveType=3");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);


        ManagementObjectCollection retObjectCollection = searcher.Get ( );

        return retObjectCollection;
    }

    public static void FillRow(Object obj, out SqlString Name, out SqlDecimal Capacity, out SqlDecimal Freespace)
    {
        ManagementObject m = (ManagementObject)obj;

        Name = new SqlString((string)m["name"]);


        Int64 int64cap;
        Int64.TryParse(m["Capacity"].ToString(), out int64cap);
        decimal decCap;
        decCap = int64cap / 1073741824; // to GB
        decCap = Math.Round(decCap, 2);
        Capacity = new SqlDecimal(decCap);

        Int64 int64Free;
        Int64.TryParse(m["Freespace"].ToString(), out int64Free);
        decimal decFree;
        decFree = int64Free / 1073741824; // to GB
        decFree = Math.Round(decFree, 2);
        Freespace = new SqlDecimal(decFree);




    }


}
```

The SQL to run this stuff:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [MyFirstAssembly]
FROM 'C:\MyFirstAssembly.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[WMIQuery]()
RETURNS  TABLE (
    [Name] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [Capacity] decimal(18,2) NULL,
    [Freespace] decimal(18,2) NULL
) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [MyFirstAssembly].[WMIQuery].[InitMethod]
GO

select * from WMIQuery()
```

Comment: good job figuring out that the underlying type is `UInt64` / `ulong`. I posted a simplified version in my answer :)  (no need for the expensive convert to `string` only to do `TryParse` / convert again).

Answer (score 1):

As you found out, the error is due to `m["Capacity"]` being an unsigned, not signed, Int64. To fix, just use the `Convert` class as follows:

```
        Capacity = new SqlInt64(Convert.ToInt64(m["Capacity"]));
        Freespace = new SqlInt64(Convert.ToInt64(m["Freespace"]));
```

I tested this with your code, got the same error before making any changes, and then made the change recommended above and I now get the correct output.

While not part of the problem here but just in general (initially there was a `String Querytext` input param): For input parameters / return types, please use `Sql*` types instead of native types for most datatypes (`object` for `SQL_VARIANT` and `DateTime` for `DATETIME2` are notable exceptions). So, use `SqlString` instead of `String` for the `Querytext` parameter (or just remove the input parameter as it is not being used). You can get the native .NET `string` out of the parameter by using the `Value` property (e.g. `Querytext.Value`), which all `Sql*` types have (which returns the expected native type in each case).

For more info on using SQLCLR in general, please visit: [SQLCLR Info](https://sqlclr.org/)

**HOWEVER,** and possibly more importantly: looking at exactly what you are querying via WMI, it looks like you are getting info that there is already a DMV for, `sys.dm_os_volume_stats`. You could get the exact same info, for all drives / volumes that you already have files on by using the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT vol.[volume_mount_point], vol.[volume_id], vol.[logical_volume_name],
                vol.[file_system_type], vol.[total_bytes], vol.[available_bytes],
                (vol.[total_bytes] - vol.[available_bytes]) AS [used_bytes]
FROM sys.master_files files
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(files.[database_id], files.[file_id]) vol
```

Comment: I've tried your suggested solution, but still getting the error Msg 6260, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
An error occurred while getting new row from user defined Table Valued Function : 
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
System.InvalidCastException: 
   at WMIQuery.FillRow(Object obj, SqlString& Name, SqlInt64& Capacity, SqlInt64& Freespace)

Comment: I'm aware of sys.dm_os_volume_stats, but this is more an expample CLR to be a template for other wmi queries that i want to run.

Comment: @Niklas I just updated my answer. The solution is simpler (and more efficient) than the answer you just accepted. And it does work with your code.